# Questions regarding Elementary Set Notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am struggling with summation notation! I am attempting to perform the statements that are in **bold**.

$$\ A = \text{{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}} $$
$$\ B = \text{{3, 5}} $$
$$\ C = \left\{(i, j) : i \in A, j \in B, i + j =3 \right\}$$
$$\ D = \left\{ \left\{i,j \right\} : i \in A, j \in B, i+j = 3 \right\} $$

**List all the elements of C**
I understand that:
(i, j) is a tuple  (or ordered set)
(i,j) "such that" ... i is an element of A, j is an element of B

What I don't understand:
Is this an ordered set, nested inside an unordered set?
would the output be in (i1, j1), (i2, j2) format?
not sure what to do with the i+j=3 portion of the statement?

**List all the elements of D**
I understand:
{i, j} is an unordered set.

What I don't understand:
Does (i,j) versus {i,j} make any significant changes?
Would the output be similar to that of C?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Listing all elements of C will indeed involve listing elements of the form (i,j) where i is from A and j is from B subject to the additional condition that the sum of i and j must be 3, that is, i + j= 3. I'll give you one such element of C: (0,3). Notice that 0 is in A, and 3 is in B, and 0+3 = 3. (3,0) is not an element of C, since as you pointed out, this is an ordered pair, and 3 is not in A and 0 is not in B. What will be other elements in C?

Comment: $\{\}$ always mean sets. Sets are always unordered (and no duplicates) unless otherwise specified. $\{f(x)\,:\,P(x)\}$ means the set of things $f(x)$ such that $P(x)$ is true. Most mathematicians would tell you that $(a,b)$ is an ordered pair. Sets do not contain duplicates so the question wants you to remove any duplicates you find.

Comment: I edited your tags because this question has nothing to do with index notation, or summation of any kind. It is about very elementary set theory and set-builder notation.

Comment: @HerrWarum If I understand your explanation correctly, (0,3) would be the only element that meets the i+j=3 criteria. Pairs that would not meet the constraint include (1,3)(2,3)(3,3)(4,3)(0,5)(1,5)(2,5)(3,5)(4,5).  Does this mean that C = {0,3}?

Comment: @Tommy the elements of C are ordered pairs; they are of the form (a,b), so C is {(0,3)}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I don't understand:
>   Is this an ordered set, nested inside an unordered set?

Yes. Each element of $C$ looks like $(a, b)$.

> would the output be in (i1, j1), (i2, j2) format?

What's an "output"? You're just asked to list some elements, so give this list in whatever your preferred way of giving a list is. Use bullet points or whatever. There's nothing formal and set-notational going on here.

> Does this mean that C = {0,3}?

Almost. It means that $C = \{(0,3)\}$. (*This* is set notation!) Alternatively, here is a list of all the elements in $C$, using bullet points because that's how I like to list things:

- $(0,3)$

and that's it.

> Does (i,j) versus {i,j} make any significant changes?

In this case, no. Can you think of examples where it might? What would happen if $A = B = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$, for example?

Comment: thank you for the assistance! So C = {(0,3)} and D = {0,3}? In the case where A=B= {0,1,2,3,4} there would be a lot more combinations that would satisfy i+j=3!

Comment: C = {(0,3)}, because (0,3) is the only element in C. Can you apply the same logic to D? :)

Comment: And yes, correct! In the case where A=B={0,1,2,3,4}, for example, C would also contain the element (2,1). Can you list the elements of C? What about the elements of D? How many of each are there?

Comment: I've kind of confused myself with D. If I write out the number pairs, I get the same exact combinations that I did for C. Does D = {{i,j} ...} also state that the elements should be listed in a (x,y) style? I guess it wouldn't make much sense to write D = {0,3} if it should be a pair of numbers. I now understand that C was written as {(0,3)} because of C = {(i, j)...} but I guess I don't fully understand the implications of {{i,j} ...}?

Comment: D is the set containing the single element {0,3}. It might help if you think of set notation { ... } as a bag. D = {{0,3}}, which is a bag *containing a bag* containing the numbers 0 and 3.